# Container Builder not tagging images correctly, $TAG_NAME not working

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-container-builder

I am tagging my images locally with:

```
git describe --tags --always --dirty
```

and get a short seven character hash I can tag my images with.

However in Google Container Builder, when I set the image name to

```
gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/amal-img:$COMMIT_SHA
```

[image]

I get a really long tag `gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/amal-img/amal-img:00528e0498ebb746d047de3bb38e483b69f72d89`

When I try to use one of the available variables, `$TAG_NAME` instead, i.e
`gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/amal-img/amal-img:$TAG_NAME`

I get the error message `Failed to trigger build: Request contains an invalid argument.`

Comment: When you use `TAG_NAME`, do you switch the Google Cloud Build type to `tag`? 

If you use the `branch` type, it won't have the `TAG_NAME` variable set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not listed in the "Supported variables" field text in your screenshot, but you might be able to use `$SHORT_SHA` instead - it's given as a supported substitution [in the docs](https://cloud.google.com/container-builder/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values):

```
$SHORT_SHA : The first seven characters of COMMIT_SHA
```